# Can I use sudo to create a symlink letting me modify files as my user that normally require sudo?

Tags: sudo, files, root, symbolic-link

I want to update files directly on a remote host from my desktop. The issue is that the files are all owned by `root`. I have access to `root`, but I don't have the ability to tell WebStorm that "when you upload these files, you need to also `sudo su` first".

Can I somehow, as root, enter into my user directory, create a symlink to the location I want to update files in, and allow my normal user to access/modify files from that symlink freely? Or is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: You can't do it using sym links, you should provide more details about the paths, ownerships, permissions, users ... to make us able to help you.

Comment: Independent from the owner and protection set for the symbolic link, only owner and protection of the target are used. So the only way is to modify owner/protection of the target file(s) or directory. I do not know what WebStorm does in this context; for normal programs, setting "root" as owner and the suid bit allows it to run as root, independent from who called the program.

Comment: @ridgy Simply making the program `setuid` without considering the consequences seems unwise to me.

Comment: Did you try it using `chmod` and `chown`? You could give the ownership like `chown root:webStormUser filename` to let the file be owned by root and the group "webStormUser" and do `chmod g+wr filename` to allow the group members of the group "webStormUser" to read/write